# Socket.io connect with server offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

How do I detect if the server is offline, or for some other reason cannot connect. My code looks something like this.

```
this.socket = io.connect(connectionInfo, {
    reconnect:false
});
```

It does not throw any error, so a try/catch clause is not working.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use

- `this.socket.on("connect", callback)` to catch connection events
- `this.socket.on("disconnect", callback)` to catch disconnection events
- `this.socket.on("connect_failed", callback)` to catch failed connection attempts
- `this.socket.io.on("connect_error", callback)` to catch if the server is offline

You can find all events, at https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events

Comment: In case this helps other folks finding this-- the "connect_failed" and "reconnect_failed" events are not properly fired in the 0.9.x versions of Socket.io (including 0.9.16).  More details here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/652   and a workaround here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/7BynuejEmts

Answer (score 4):

Since the 1.0 update, connection events are different.
read this page for more info: http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/

In my case, i could detect a connection error like so:

```
var manager = io.Manager('http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000', { /* options */ });
manager.socket('/namespace');
manager.on('connect_error', function() {
    console.log("Connection error!");
});

this.socket = io.connect('http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000');
```

Answer (score 2):

If your server is offline and Client tries to connect use:

```
socket.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

So Client knows he can not reach the server.

Comment: After some testing, it does not appear to work this way in the latest stable Socket.io client (v0.9.16)