# Prevent closing connection on bad request

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I have an express server.
I set `socket.setKeepAlive(true, 60000);` in order to maintain persistent connection for at least 1min.

Here is the code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.write("Hello Riko");
});

// server.listen(3000);

server.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log("A new connection was made by a client.");
  socket.setKeepAlive(true, 60000);
  socket.on("data", data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
  // 30 second timeout. Change this as you see fit.
});
```

When the client send invalid request, it receives `400 Bad Request`
How to prevent connection close on invalid request?

Comment: This appears to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248128/socket-io-connect-with-server-offline

It looks like you can catch `disconnect` events

Comment: I is good to know. What I actually want is to tell express: Hey Express l, don't close the connection  if you don't like the request.

Comment: I think I found the solution: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_clienterror  Haven't  tested it yet though. Tomorrow I will test it an report the results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the suggestion i made in the comments works.

`server.on('clientError',cb)` prevents the default behavior of the stack.

I encountered one problem though. It registers event listener for `error` event every time `clientError` is fired. Therefore I changed the code litle bit and ended up with a  solution that works for me:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello Riko");
});

onSocketError = err => {
  console.log("Socket Error: " + err);
};

server.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("data", data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
  console.log("A new connection was made by a client.");
});
server.on("clientError", (err, socket) => {
  socket.removeAllListeners("error");
});
```

Hope this would help someone with similar problem.